# drupal mail printout message

Tags: 7, emails

I have created a module which calls drupal_mail. The emailing works fine, but everytime it emails, it prints out a whole page of text, each line starting with SMTP->, showing you exactly what is happening. I want to get rid of this and I don't know how. The most I have been able to do is to put a 'return' at the end of the function which calls drupal_mail, but the only help this gives me is that now I can at least see the rest of the screen; without that 'return' the only thing on the page is this printout. 
Here is an example of the printout:

```
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 250-8BITMIME " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 HELP " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 250 HELP " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtpout06.vgs.untd.com Hello user-1087smi.cable.mindspring.com pleased to meet you 250-SIZE 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5 250 HELP 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "235 smtpout06.vgs.untd.com auth ok, go ahead " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "235 smtpout06.vgs.untd.com auth ok, go ahead " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "" 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 admin@domain.com... Sender OK " 
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data is "250 admin@domain.com... Sender OK " 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 admin@domain.com... Sender OK
```

EDIT: 
Here is the code I used. I basically copied it out of the example email module that is on the drupal site:

```
function athletics_subscriptions_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
global $user;

// Each message is associated with a language, which may or may not be the
// current user's selected language, depending on the type of e-mail being
// sent. This $language variable is used later in the t() calls for subject
// and body to ensure the proper translation takes effect.
$language = $message['language'];

switch ($key) {
// Send a simple message from the contact form.
case 'accepted':
  $message['subject'] = t('Subscription Accepted', array('@site-name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')), $language->language);
  // Note that the message body is an array, not a string.
  $message['body'][] = t('Your subscription was approved.', array('@name' => $user->name), $language->language);
  // Because this is just user-entered text, we do not need to translate it.
  $message['body'][] = $params['message'];
  break;
case 'rejected':
  $message['subject'] = t('Subscription Rejected', array('@site-name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')), $language->language);
  // Note that the message body is an array, not a string.
  $message['body'][] = t('Your subscription was rejected.', array('@name' => $user->name), $language->language);
  // Because this is just user-entered text, we do not need to translate it.
  $message['body'][] = $params['message'];
case 'alert':
  $message['subject'] = t('Update', array('@site-name' => variable_get('site_name', 'Drupal')), $language->language);
  // Note that the message body is an array, not a string.
  $message['body'][] = t('Your subscribed team was updated', array('@name' => $user->name), $language->language);
  // Because this is just user-entered text, we do not need to translate it.
  $message['body'][] = $params['message']; 
  break;    
}
}

/**
* Send an e-mail.
*
 * @param $form_values
 *   An array of values from the contact form fields that were submitted.
 *   There are just two relevant items: $form_values['email'] and
 *   $form_values['message'].
 */
function authorization_response_mail_send($staff_action, $first_name, $last_name, $email) {
// All system mails need to specify the module and template key (mirrored from
// hook_mail()) that the message they want to send comes from.
$module = 'athletics_subscriptions';
if($staff_action == 'accept')
{$key = 'accepted';}
else if ($staff_action == 'reject')
{$key = 'rejected';}

// Specify 'to' and 'from' addresses.
$to = $email;
$from = variable_get('site_mail', 'admin@example.com'); //clarify what i need to put here

// "params" loads in additional context for email content completion in
// hook_mail(). In this case, we want to pass in the values the user entered
// into the form, which include the message body in $form_values['message'].
//$params = $form_values;

// The language of the e-mail. This will one of three values:
// * user_preferred_language(): Used for sending mail to a particular website
//   user, so that the mail appears in their preferred language.
// * global $language: Used when sending a mail back to the user currently
//   viewing the site. This will send it in the language they're currently
//   using.
// * language_default(): Used when sending mail to a pre-existing, 'neutral'
//   address, such as the system e-mail address, or when you're unsure of the
//   language preferences of the intended recipient.
//
// Since in our case, we are sending a message to a random e-mail address that
// is not necessarily tied to a user account, we will use the site's default
// language.
$language = language_default();

// Whether or not to automatically send the mail when drupal_mail() is
// called. This defaults to TRUE, and is normally what you want unless you
// need to do additional processing before drupal_mail_send() is called.
$send = TRUE;
// Send the mail, and check for success. Note that this does not guarantee
// message delivery; only that there were no PHP-related issues encountered
// while sending.
$result = drupal_mail($module, $key, $to, $language, $params = array(), $from, $send);
if ($result['result'] == TRUE) {
drupal_set_message(t('Your message has been sent.'));
}
else {
drupal_set_message(t('There was a problem sending your message and it was not sent.'), 'error');
}
```

}

Comment: Post the code that you are using which calls Drupal mail. Also please use the code format options when pasting printout text like this.

Comment: Are you using something like the SMTP module? Did you turn on debugging in that module?

Comment: No I'm not. At one point in time I had that module enabled, but it has not been enabled for a long time now.